# Moving average and trends in cloudwatch metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to have a moving average or a trend line in the metrics of aws cloudwatch?

The idea is to show for example the cpu utilization of a server over time and not just the average of the last x minutes, so we can see if the trend over long period of time is going up or down.

Answer (score 1):

CloudWatch does not have trend lines built into standard metrics.

If you're looking for this you can enable this you would need to setup [anomaly detection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Anomaly_Detection.html) for the metric.

By enabling this you will be able to build up an overview of the trends for that metric whilst also configuring the normal/abnormal ranges for the metric. If your data goes outside this line you can have a CloudWatch alarm notify you.

Comment: I saw that and it is not really gives me what I am looking for. That metric I want is to show the server performance has improved over the last 2 months.

Comment: Unfortunately theres no trendline support directly from CloudWatch. If you can calculate what the metric value would be you could of course use custom metrics.Other than that you'd need to look for a third party vendor that supports both CloudWatch and the ability to calculate a trend line for your metrics